# How can one generate unique values for each row in a new column in a mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

This seems conceptually simple, but once I put it in SQL terminology, it got difficult.

Say one has 3 rows in a table called "stuff".

```
 col1     col2     col3
 ------   ------   ------
 aaaa     bbbb     cccc
 xxxx     yyyy     zzzz
 aaaa     bbbb     cccc
```

Suppose I want to add a pk column and give it unique values. There is no SQL that I can give in an update that will update the 1st and not the 3rd row. But it turns out that an extension to SQL that MySQL allows gives an answer.

```
 alter table stuff add column pk int;
 update table set pk = 1 where pk is NULL limit 1;
 update table set pk = 2 where pk is NULL limit 1;
 update table set pk = 3 where pk is NULL limit 1;
```

This gives me:

```
 pk       col1     col2     col3
 ------   ------   ------   ------
 1        aaaa     bbbb     cccc
 2        xxxx     yyyy     zzzz
 3        aaaa     bbbb     cccc
```

But it turns out that if you do this with a table of over 5 million rows, it is taking an extremely long time. I have a guess that it is doing a bunch of work to find *all* the rows with a pk = NULL, when what I really ever want is just one.

Does anyone know why this would run slowly? Is there a faster or more SQL-compatible way to do this? I cannot think what it would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is slow because your `IS NULL` condition will produce `FULL SCAN` each time - and that is because, obviously, you can't still use index on the column (you have not it yet)

You can use MySQL [variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) to generate your unique values. That will be:

```
UPDATE stuff CROSS JOIN (SELECT @pk:=0) AS init SET stuff.pk=@pk:=@pk+1
```

Comment: Wow. Well, that does not look like standard SQL either but it is very cool. And way faster. I have been using MySQL for a while and have never had to use variables. Guess I should learn. Thanx